Courtroom drama with supposedly innocent rapists, with plot twist
American courtroom drama from the 1980's
There is this film, and I may actually be confusing it with another similar film (making this a double question) where someone is trying to prove the innocence of some accused rapists in a small town in the American South. They enlist the help of a retired lawyer (that I could swear was played by Donald Sutherland but I can't find the film on his wikipedia) that has fallen into alcoholism. He becomes sober enough to defend them and then there is a plot twist at the end, possibly that they were guilty after all.
My recollections of this (or these!) film is very vague, but I hope someone recognises the general idea.
EDIT:
So Donald Sutherland may not be in it, and the concept of the retired drunk lawyer may also be taken from A Time To Kill. Not much left to go on then. As I remember, the defendants were supposed to have passed through a town and raped someone, and then their family wanted to prove their innocence. They get someone to do that, and just as the lawyer is celebrating the victory with his friends on a terrace he finds out that the family was bluffing. Something like that.

Well, then again, there's also another Southern thing with Sean Connery as a jura professor getting a black guy out of death row (for killing a little girl, I think) who  at the end turns out to have done it. Ed Harris (another convict) and Laurence Fishburn (sheriff) are in it, too. But it doesn't really match that well either.

"Just Cause", that's it! That matches everything that is left when A Time To Kill is taken out of the equation! If you make this an answer I will accept it, thanks!

Well, it doesn't really match that much of your info. But ok, I'll try to write an answer.

According to wikipedia, the girl was first raped. So we have the South, rape/murder, proved innocent, plot twist: guilty. The rest is from A Time To Kill.

Seeing that my previous answer rules out A Time to Kill as half of your mixed up memory, a possibility for the other half, which you say still exists as an individual movie, would be 1995's Just Cause.

Bobby Earl is facing the electric chair for the murder of a young girl. Eight years after the crime he calls in Paul Armstrong, a professor of law, to help prove his innocence. Armstrong quickly uncovers some overlooked evidence to present to the local police, but they aren't interested - Bobby was their killer.




This puts Sean Connery (who might be confused with Donald Sutherland, especially when seeing their roles in the two movies specifically) as a retired lawyer who retracted to jura professorship. He is dragged into the case of an African American in death row for allegedly raping and murdering a white girl in the depths of the Florida province. With his investigations Connery gets him out of jail.

 But at the end it is revealed that it was all a ploy and he did commit the crimes and it ends in a suspenseful finale when the convict kidnaps Connery's own family, I think.

It doesn't fit in so many details either, I'm not sure the convict's family is involved in getting Connery on the case and neither am I sure about him sitting on a terrace, but it has the rape, the plot-twist, the retired lawyer (who looks a bit like Sutherland) and the Southern setting. Together with the images of A Time to Kill that are likely mixed into it (and which was released around roughly the same time), it might have a good chance to be what you're looking for.

This is definitely it, thank you very much for the excellent answer. I will watch it tonight to see how close it was to my memory of it! I was picturing Matthew McConaughey on that terrace, so it is probably a contamination. The crucial thing here was the plot twist, so I am certain this is it the real deal!

I think you might be partly confusing the John Grisham adaptation A Time to Kill from 1996.

In Canton, Mississippi, 10-year-old Tonya Hailey is viciously brutalized by two white racist rednecks -- James Louis "Pete" Willard and Billy Ray Cobb. Almost immediately after Tonya is found and rushed to a hospital, Pete and Billy Ray are found at a roadside bar, where they had been bragging about what they did to Tonya. Tonya's understandably distraught and enraged father, Carl Lee Hailey, remembers a case from a year ago, when four white men raped an African-American girl in a nearby town, and got acquitted. Carl is determined to not let that happen in this case. While deputy Dwayne Powell Looney is escorting Pete and Billy Ray up a flight of stairs to a court room, Carl emerges from the building's basement with an assault rifle, and he kills Pete and Billy Ray for what they did to Tonya. Carl is later arrested at his house by African-American sheriff Ozzie Walls, and Carl is scheduled to be placed on trial. Despite the efforts of the NAACP and local African-American leaders to...




It puts Matthew McConaughey as a lawyer defending Samuel L. Jackson, who actually shot the rapists of his daughter. Donald Sutherland plays his mentor who has retired and sworn to not enter a court ever again, but he isn't really a drunkard or actively working in court during the movie. There is however another part where they get the help of a psychiatrist in court (to pledge for "criminally insane") and he is quite drunk in one scene. There isn't much of a plot twist at the end either, though. But the whole movie has a very "Southern" atmosphere and thematics.
This movie doesn't fit in all parts, but I'd say it is definitely playing into your memories.

Thank you for the thoughtful answer! This must be where I got Donald Sutherland from, and possibly the drunkenness and the retired lawyer themes as well. I am fairly sure that the movie I am thinking of exists and is different from this though!
